# Python ZipFile Package Extraction Error/Bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

So, I'm working on a python project that I've been working on ever since December of 2021. And whenever I extract all files from the zip file using the ZipFile module, it successfully extracts one file with all of data in it. But the 2nd one which is supposed to have data results to 0 bytes after extraction.

Does anyone know what is going on?

I tried using this piece of code but it ended up not working since it gave me the same result.

```
if split[1].endswith('.zip') or split[1].endswith('.ZIP'): ## Checks if file ends with the *.zip file format from user input.
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(split[1]) as zpkg_ref:
            zpkg_ref.extractall(tmpfolder) ## Extracts every file in the *.zip file to the temporary folder.
        except:
            print(f'[SYSTEM] Couldn\'t extract \'{split[1]}\'.') ## If couldn't extract, throw an error.
            continue
```

Comment: Never, ever use a bare `except:`. Now you have no way of knowing what the actual error is.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is, is that that's not the thing I'm worrying about since it extracted correctly but with one file only having it's data. And if it didn't it would've threw an error already.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't throw an exception, then it's probably something to do with the second file. Maybe it's corrupt? Hard to say.

Comment: Just checked the file and it isn't corrupted at all.

Comment: Then you'll need to use a debugger to see what is or isn't being written by `zipfile`.

Comment: So I just checked the file and I wrote it to the first file. And now the first file is 0 bytes now. About the second file is that it is a json file containing json data so I don't know what is going on